# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add', why?

Tags: python, django

So I refer to another model :

```
 subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Season)
```

So I use :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def buy_season(request):
    _id = 1
    season = Season.objects.get(id = _id)

    a = ExtUser.subscriptions.add(season)

    a.save()

    return Response({'status': 'success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I get an error object 'ManyToManyDescriptor' does not attribute the "Add"
Do many to many directly , and not through the " throw " , why there is this error ?

Comment: Is `ExtUser` an instance of your model?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye With ExtUser I rewrote the standard model of the user

Comment: @MosesKoledoye subscriptions field belongs to ExtUser

Comment: You can only add an object to an instance of a model, not the class object.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye 
Now I stared at the text and understand it, thanks . I have to go to sleep :)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye write an answer, i note his faithful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use an instance of the `ExtUser` model as you cannot add a model object directly to a class object.

Answer (score 3):

User instance instead of class.

```
a = ExtUser.objects.get(id=user_id).subscriptions.add(season)
```

You need to update the above query and it will fix the issue.